# How can I make a running text strip at the bottom of my video, please help

Tags: text-object

How can I make a running ( horizontal) text strip at the bottom of my video. I have used text strip and currently using blender 2.79.

Request you to please help or if any video is available please let me know , will be of great help.

Thanks

Comment: Please attach an image or gif on how you want it to be. Otherwise this question shows no effort on research. Before asking question check this out-https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Thank u

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way would be to do the animation manually if you don't have too much text. just specify a keyframe with the position of your text outside of the camera output, then move that as you need and specify that with a new keyframe.
[image: you can see the text out of the camera's field of view at the start of the animation]

[image: at the end the text will be on the right]

And i recorded a video how to do it https://youtu.be/PE0jZ1-nzlQ

Comment: in the Graph Editor (or Dope Sheet) press T to make the movement Linear (instead of moving the curve handles)